# Help in push-pull MOSFET circuit design (gate drivers)

Tags: mosfet, gate-driving, push-pull

Background:

- I need to drive a 24 volt device from a (buffered and optoisolated) GPIO output. The device connected may be either low- or high side switched, so I guess push-pull is the way to go.
- Switching frequency is very low, a few Hz is enough, but either state might be constant for hours at a time. Speed is not an issue.
- Source/sink current should be at the 0-500mA region (output might be connected to a high impedance logic input, or a inductive or resistive load (relay/indicator light)

I'm looking at different gate driver IC's, and the beefier ones basically almost can do them by themselves, but they are not exactly designed for long periods of power dissipation so it probably is not a good solution.

If I have a gate driver with one output (for example FOD8343) and connect the output to both of the gates of a push-pull configured power MOSFETs, my understanding I'll probably end up with shoot-through and smoke?

Then there are these high-low gate drivers, which have then separate inputs for high- and low side outputs. These I probably need to forget, as I only have one signal (I wouldn't want to split the signal, and drive some logic NOT etc.)

So would my best bet be synchronous buck driver? Or some other circuit to delay the transition for the other FET?

Comment: Why not simply use relays? Then you can get rid of the optoisolation and shave down your BoM.

Comment: Use two FOD8343 and some logic gates on the IR diode side to apply anti-shoot-through.

Comment: Thank you @Lundin for you comment. I didn't thought of that.

These both seem like probable solutions. I'll study the "relay route" a bit further, it would ease my BoM...